# output shows the type like Atom or Variable not the actual value of the variable(pyswip in python)

Tags: python, prolog

I am running the python program which is exectuing prolog queries(using pyswip library)
the problem in this is that i am not getting the value of  the variable in the output instead i am getting type of it like Atom/Variable with some address.

here is the code,

```
from pyswip import Prolog
swipl = Prolog()
swipl.retractall('car(_)')
swipl.assertz('(fun(X) :- car(X),red(X))')

#swipl.assertz('car(porcshe)')
swipl.assertz('car(Mercedez)')
swipl.assertz('car(Buggati)')
swipl.assertz('car(Audi)')

print (list(swipl.query('car(Which)')))
```

Output:-

```
[{'Which': Variable(100)}, {'Which': Variable(100)}, {'Which': Variable(70)}]
```

Why it is giving output like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Prolog variables start with an upper case letter and constants start with a lower case letter.

So your program:

```
car(Mercedes).
car(Bugatti).
car(Audi).
```

Allows for any substitution:

```
?- car(beethoven).
true ;    % Mercedes = beethoven
true ;    % Bugatti = beethoven
true.     % Audi = beethoven
```

A shorter version of your program would be:

```
car(_Anything).
```

But you probably don't want that anything is a car. Try replacing the variables by constants (mercedes, bugatti, audi).

Regarding `Variable(100)`: when you use the underscore as a don't care notation for the contents of a variable or Prolog has to introduce variables for other reasons, they usually just get a number. I assume to distinguish the variable #100 from the nuber 100, they write `Variable(100)`- you can recognize it's not a Prolog term because `Variable` would be a variable but variables don't have arguments. So if you parse the output it would be clear what is meant.

Comment: Thnku for your detailed answer and noticing that capital letter(i didn't see that coming). got ur point regarding Variavle(100)

Comment: Can yoy share some resources or Documentation which will make my understanding better in using pyswip in python: @lambda.xy.x

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with pyswip, just general Prolog - but I'll see if i can find out what to do in below's code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the above answer is working fine for the above code but for the below code it is showing similar type of problem,

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
p.retractall('tran(_,_)')
p.retractall('listtran(_,_)')
p.assertz('tran(eins,one)')
p.assertz('tran(zwei,two)')
p.assertz('tran(drei,three)')
p.assertz('tran(vier,four)')
p.assertz('tran(fuenf,five)')
p.assertz('tran(sechs,six)')
p.assertz('tran(sieben,seven)')
p.assertz('tran(acht,eight)')
p.assertz('tran(neun,nine)')    
p.assertz('listtran([],[])')
p.assertz('listtran([X|Tx],[Y|Ty]) :- tran(X,Y) , listtran(Tx,Ty)')

Val = list(p.query('listtran([eins,zwei,drei,vier],Z)'))
print(Val)
```

Output:-

```
[{'Z': [Atom('468997'), Atom('469381'), Atom('469765'), Atom('470149')]}]
```

Comment: When Prolog derives a fact, it returns an answer substitution, i.e. an assignment of the variables in your query that's necessary for it to be true. In your case it's `Z = [one, two, three, four].`. Apparently the assignment is represented as an associative array and Prolog lists seem to be represented as Python lists. That could explain the structure `[{'Z' : [ .... ] }]` but why atoms are not mapped back to names, I don't have a good guess for. Perhaps there is a separate function for this in pyswip?

Comment: Btw, better use a new question for a follow up - it might be confusing for others that read later :)

Comment: yeah sure i'll do it , apart from that, as i am in the initial learning stages of prolog and pyswip i dont know about other functions.  Thnx for your time.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, I am also facing the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, found answer. You can check the following:
https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/issues/65